# Representing a truth-table

Tags: c, data-structures

I have the following data which I would like to represent efficiently in C. Retrieval time is favoured over memory consumption, yet I would be happy not to drain all my memory.

Input values are sequences *l_1, ..., l_n* of logical values `0`, `1` or `?` (undef). Each sequence corresponds to a sequence of outputs *l_1, ..., l_m* of logical values (from the same universe).

The data is sparse. (The input-output mapping is only given for some sequences of inputs and implicit rules apply otherwise.)

I considered:

- Using hashing with good worst-case bounds. But that's a little unpleasant as I would have to hash the input sequence. For input sequences sufficiently long, this will deplete any (unsigned) integer quickly.
- The use of trie, but then, if I was given a few dense tables, I would end up doing tons of memallocs and fragmenting the heap. And it probably wouldn't cache well.

Yet another unpleasant fact is that I have to remember the output *sequence*, which is variable in length. In the program, several instances of the data structure being discussed exist, each of which has different *m* and *n* values.

You may think of this problem as representing the truth-table for a propositional formula, except the output of the formula is multi-valued, the logic is ternary and the formula is unknown.

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: "For input sequences sufficiently long, this will deplete any (unsigned) integer quickly." is a false conclusion.  Hash values generated from different sequences do not need to be unique.  Hash tables always have to deal with collisions.  All that is important is that collisions are rare.   Post some upper bounds for `m` and `n` : 16, 256, 64K 4G, `UINT_MAX` etc.

Comment: do you know the max values n,m can take?

Comment: Unfortunately, no bound are given for m, n; I assume I shouldn't rely upon the fact they won't exceed any fixed value.